# Weird Glitch when render only normals

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, image

Hey guys i dont know whats happening, new to blender. Hahaha...sigh
Ok so i am following blender guru tutorial but for the love of god i cant figure it out a render glitch. i am using an Hdri to light the scene and I got this weird glitch. Without texture only a principled shader with a normal baked.

Screenshot
[image]

As you can see I only have the normal and hdri so i dont know were that camouflage glitch is coming from.
Also it looks perfectly fine in the renderer viewport the one acess directly throught the 3d vieport.

[image]

I know the normal bake is not good i was just testing how it looked with the normals in the final render and i got those weird white gray and black spots. I know about noise problems from sampling and such, but these seems to be an issue with the shader itself
Any help or insight will be eternnally apreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Edit: Ok at least I know this, only as a pointer to whoever can help. I try making another material and Input the normals, it worked it stop the glitching but if I put color data on the diffuse input, the white, gray and black spots appear again. Heeelp please :(

Comment: maybe your normal bake is not in tangent space? try changing that in your Normalmap Node. Also specify the UV the texture should use directly